# Archiving mail solution for virtual users

Tags: email, postfix, archive

Hi I'm using postfix with virtual mail users on Zarafa Collab Platform. I have the requirement of archiving all inbound and outgoing mail. I know that you can use the always_bcc option on postfix to deliver the mail but Zarafa is storing mail on a DB i don't want the archive mail to be stored on the db as well since it will be huge. Therefore I would like to know if this archiving mail can be stored using maildir or mbox format to a local linux user? If so how could i configure it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for an open source email archiving application](http://serverfault.com/questions/42006/looking-for-an-open-source-email-archiving-application)

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to re-route the mail addressed to the archive to a different delivery point, however it's not a very neat solution.

I'd recommend using a [milter](https://www.milter.org/milters/archiving/alphabetical/1). IIRC [Postfix does support milters](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).